# Y axis ticks with wrong rotation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3 graph in which the x axis ticks are like this:

[image]

The code segment for doing that is the following

```
                  vis.append("svg:g")
                      .attr("class", "x axis")
                      .style({ 'stroke': 'Black', 'fill': 'none', 'stroke-width': '1px' })
                      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - margin.bottom) + ")")                          
                      .call(xAxis)
                      .selectAll("text")
                      .attr("y", 0)
                      .attr("x", 9)
                      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
                      .attr("transform", "rotate(120)")
                      .style("text-anchor", "start");
```

The thing is that labels are not readable. For example, "August" should start with "A", not with "t" like in the image I've attached.

I tried changing "rotate" value, even it did not help.

Can someone help me to position the labels correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of rotating `120`, try to rotate `-40` (changing the `text-anchor` to `end`).

Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg")
var scale = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([20, 280])
  .domain(["foo", "bar", "baz"]);
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale);
var gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis)
  .selectAll("text")
  .attr("transform", "translate(-10,0) rotate(-40)")
  .style("text-anchor", "end");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```